# weird tableview behavior when cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, cell

My tableview has a weird behavior when a cell is selected but this behavior is not seen always. When a cell has been selected some cells which are below the selected cell moves. These two gifs will show you the behavior in the two cases when it is shown and when it doesn't appear. 
this is the
[tableview without weird behavior](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W9zbKIUEKQ_gAbKZm8i7NbaOIq1D7cgu) and this is the [tableview with the weird behavior](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L0MaF0c6lKqzQpwC-M4Ygb4wHt3DHsB7)
and this is my code :

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : UserTableViewCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell") as? UserTableViewCell)!
    if(self.firebaseUsers.count != 0){
    cell.influentBackgroudView.layer.cornerRadius=10
        let url = URL.init(string:  String().loadCorrectUrl(url:firebaseUsers[indexPath.row].image))
        cell.influentImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        cell.influentImageView!.sd_setImage(with: url!, placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "placeholder"),options: [.continueInBackground,.progressiveDownload], completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
            if (error != nil) {
                cell.influentImageView!.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
            } else {
                cell.influentImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                cell.influentImageView.image = image
            }

        })
        cell.influentImageView.layer.cornerRadius=10
        cell.influentImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.influentNameLabel.text=" " + firebaseUsers[indexPath.row].name + " "
        cell.influentNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell.influentNameLabel.textAlignment = .center
        if(selectedCellIndex==indexPath ){
        cell.influentBackgroudView.isHidden=false
            }
        else{
            cell.influentBackgroudView.isHidden=true
            }
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    }

    return cell 
} 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let previousIndex=selectedCellIndex
        selectedCellIndex=indexPath
        if(previousIndex==selectedCellIndex){
            let nextVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VisitedProfileViewController") as! VisitedProfileViewController
            nextVC.passedUser = firebaseUsers[selectedCellIndex!.row]
            navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
        }
        if(previousIndex==nil){
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with:.none)
        }
        else{
            if(previousIndex != indexPath){
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath,previousIndex!], with: .none)
            }
            else {
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)

                }
        }
}
```

thank you guys for your help!

Comment: There is probably no need to reload any of the rows but since you do I assume this issue only happens when you scroll down the table view for a bit. The first suspect I would say is estimated height for row not being consistent with actual cell height. If you have static cell heights try to return the same value in estimated height delegate method. If you have automatic cell heights you can store actual heights into a dictionary `[IndexPath: CGFloat]` and use that one in your delegate. You can fill it on `didEndDisplaying` delegate method (`hightCache[indexPath] = cell.bounds.height`).

Comment: Hey Matic ! thank you for your answer, I just placed the row height constant in the estimated row height delegate method and the issue disappeared. You saved my day man! (put your comment as an answer and I will accept and vote it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As identified from the comments the issue you are facing is produced by calling `reloadRows` when you press a cell with conjunction of incorrect estimated row heights. So either reloading needs to be removed or estimated height corrected. The first solution is already covered in an answer provided by A. Amini.

Since many of such anomalies are related to estimated row height it still makes sense to improve it.

For simple static row heights you can either implement a delegate method for instance

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return indexPath.row == 0 ? 44.0 : 200.0
}
```

where the values are exactly the same as in your `heightForRowAt` method. Or if all rows have same hight you can remove this delegate method but set the heights directly in some initialization method like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.rowHeight = 200
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
}
```

When more complicated cells are introduced and automatic cell height is used we usually use a height cache of cells. It means we need to save height of a cell when it disappears so we may use it later. All heights are saved in a dictionary of type `[IndexPath: CGFloat]`. A very simple implementation should look like this:

```
private var cellHeightCache: [IndexPath: CGFloat] = [IndexPath: CGFloat]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellHeightCache[indexPath] = cell.bounds.height
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeightCache[indexPath] ?? UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

In some cases extra work is needed like clearing the cache when table view is reloaded.

The reason why this is happening is because table view will not reload cells around the cells you currently see but rather check the content offset and compute which cells you were supposed to be seeing. So any call to reload may make the table view jump or animate cells due to wrong estimated row height.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was you're reloading tableView after "each" selection.
Try this code out and let me know if you need more help.

```
class MyTableViewClass: UITableViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell" as! UserTableViewCell

        if !self.firebaseUsers.isEmpty {

            cell.influentBackgroudView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            cell.influentImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

            let url = URL(string: firebaseUsers[indexPath.row].image)

            cell.influentImageView!.sd_setImage(with: url!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"),options: [.continueInBackground,.progressiveDownload], completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
                if error != nil {
                    cell.influentImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                }
            })

            cell.influentImageView.layer.cornerRadius=10
            cell.influentImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cell.influentNameLabel.text = " \(firebaseUsers[indexPath.row].name) "
            cell.influentNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            cell.influentNameLabel.textAlignment = .center

            cell.selectionStyle = .none
        }

        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let nextVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VisitedProfileViewController") as! VisitedProfileViewController
        nextVC.passedUser = firebaseUsers[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
    }
}


class UserTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if isSelected {
                // Selected behavior, like change Background to blue
            } else {
                // Deselected behavior, change Background to clear
            }
        }
    }
}
```